# Cannot pass list of objects to controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have two entities with relation as

```
@Entity
public class Foo {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;     

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo")
    private List<Bar> bars;

    // *******************\\    
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Bar{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
    private Foo foo;

    // *******************\\

}
```

I get list of bars to show in form for adding new foo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fooForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("bars", barService.findAll());
        return "add-foo";
    }
```

and form is

```
<form:form commandName="foo">
    <form:input path="name"/><br>
    <form:select path="bars" multiple="multiple">
    <c:forEach items="${bars}" var="bar">
        <form:option value="${bar.id}">${bar.title}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
    </form:select><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Foo with selected Bars">
</form:form>
```

Here I see all bars present using

```
<c:forEach items="${bars}" var="bar">
   <form:option value="${bar.id}">${bar.title}</form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

but when I submit the form, using the method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addFoo(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo) {

    List<Bar> bars = foo.getBars();
    for (Bar bar : bars ) {
        logger.info("DEBUG Foo object", bar);
    }
    return "redirect:/foos-list";
}
```

it seems not to send data to server and say an error *The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect*.

Comment: Where is the `Request mapping` to the controller from your form? Did you send the form by `GET` method or `POST` method ?

Comment: @VigNesh I have updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your binding input form fields with your `Business Domain model Object`, Make sure that Databinding is correctly performed or not. So use `BindingResult` after `@ModelAttribute. So you can easily identify your whether the form fields is bind your business object or not.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addFoo(@ModelAttribute("foo") Foo foo, BindingResult result) {

 if (!result.hasErrors()){

    List<Bar> bars = foo.getBars();
    for (Bar bar : bars ) {
        logger.info("DEBUG Foo object", bar);
    }
  } else 
      System.out.println("Binding result error");

    return "redirect:/foos-list";
}
```

And your redirect to "/foos-list" into your Controller again. There is no such `RequestMapping` in your post. So redirect to appropriate `RequestMapping` like this,

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/foos-list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String fooForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("bars", barService.findAll());
        return "add-foo";
    }
```